# Why is TortoiseSVN's show log missing revisions?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have the following repository structure

```
\root
    \Project1
        \trunk
            \file1.txt
            \file2.txt
            \folder1
                \file3.txt
```

Lets say file1.txt was changed and committed 3 times. When I choose show log on **\root\Project\trunk**, I get history including the 3 commits.

I copied the content of this project and got the following structure:

```
\root
    \Project1
    \trunk
        \file1.txt
        \file2.txt
        \folder1
            \file3.txt
```

When I choose show log on **\root\trunk**, I get history including only copy operation.

When I choose show log on **\root\trunk\file1.txt**, I get history including the 3 commits.

Why don't I get the full history when I choose show log on **\root\trunk**?

Comment: All log entries are shown relative to what path you are in. You'll see everything if you do a `show log` from the repo root. You'll only see log entries where items in `trunk` (or below trunk) changed if you enter that directory and do a `show log`.

Comment: Have you run `svn update` on `\root\trunk`?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to check for the full history, use revision as HEAD.
if you use only for a specific path, it will not show the full history

Comment: I did use the head revision.

Answer (score 0):

In TortoiseSVN, there is a "Stop on copy/rename" checkbox is the log dialog. This needs to be unchecked if you want to see revisions prior to your copy. I think by default it is checked, because when you are showing the log of a feature branch, generally only the revisions on the branch are useful for your present task.